# DAX Calculate Measure with IF Statement

Tags: if-statement, dax, measure

I am trying to count the number of codes {"1V", "2V", "3V"} contained in the [ToStatus] and [FromStatus] column of the' Master Report' table. However, I need only count the code once if it appears in both columns.

I am relatively new to DAX and the below is my attempt at coding same. I would be obliged if any of the gurus out there could be of assistance :)

Psuedo code:
If any of the values {"1V", "2V", "3V"} is in column [ToStatus] and [FromStatus]
Just count [ToStatus] else count [FromStatus] and return the total

Attempt in DAX:

```
=IF(('Master Report'[ToStatus] IN {"1V", "2V", "3V"} && 'Master Report'[FromStatus] IN {"1V", "2V", "3V"}),

CALCULATE([_PatientCount],
FILTER('Master Report',
'Master Report'[ToStatus] IN {"1V", "2V", "3V"}),

CALCULATE([_PatientCount],
FILTER('Master Report',
'Master Report'[FromStatus] IN {"1V", "2V", "3V"} ||
'Master Report'[ToStatus] IN {"1V", "2V", "3V"})
)
```

Sample Data:

ID Code             FromStatus      ToStatus

- 145320150978 3V  2V
- 145320150978 3V  2V
- 145320210617 RH  3V
- 145320210617 2V  ZO
- 145320210628 3C  2V
- 145320210628 2V  5L
- 145320211246 3V  5S

Update: Also I forgot to mention that the purpose of the _PatientCode measure is to count DISTINCT patient codes!

Update: I have now resolved this by doing it in MySQL instead of DAX and then just counting the 1 values in DAX.

Thanks in advance,
Conor.

Comment: Please post sample data as copiable text along with expected output. Also, mark your previous questions as solved.

Comment: The unique count of the V codes should be 7. There are 2 occasions where both [ToStatus] and [FromStatus] columns have V values. So the answer I am currently getting is 9 which is incorrect.

Also as I am new to this, why would I mark the question as solved if it is not yet solved?
Thansk for your help

Comment: You have asked previous questions which have been answered but provided no feedback nor marked them as solved.

Comment: Apologies will check those now

Comment: Updated now and marked as solved

Answer (score 0):

Some brackets were missing, others were superfluous:

```
MyMeasure =
IF (
    'Master Report'[ToStatus] IN { "1V", "2V", "3V" }
        && 'Master Report'[FromStatus] IN { "1V", "2V", "3V" },
    CALCULATE (
        [_PatientCount],
        FILTER ( 
            'Master Report', 
            'Master Report'[ToStatus] IN { "1V", "2V", "3V" } )
    ),
    CALCULATE (
        [_PatientCount],
        FILTER (
            'Master Report',
            'Master Report'[FromStatus] IN { "1V", "2V", "3V" }
                || 'Master Report'[ToStatus] IN { "1V", "2V", "3V" }
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: HI Peter, thanks for the comment. I am getting the following error when I try that:


"This formula is invalid or incomplete: 'Calculation error in measure 'Master Report'[My Measure]: 
A single value for column 'ToStatus' in table 'Master Report' cannot be determined. 
This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an 
aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.'."

Comment: Looks like you pasted the **Measure** into the **Calculated column** UI.

Comment: I added it as a measure as I normally would. Right clicked on table name in the pivot table fields box in excel and clicked on "Add Measure"!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved from MySQL side with code below:

(CASE
WHEN ToStatus LIKE '%V' OR FromStatus LIKE '%V' THEN 1
ELSE 0
END) as V_Count